# R Package for generating tables

Tags: r

I’m looking for some advice on possible packages for generating tables. I’m just picking up R and am used to Excel PivotTables,

Mostly the functions I’m looking for are Pivot Table like. So, that’s filters for what data gets chosen, row and column groups. Only showing the top entries and sorting from most occured to least occured would be perfect to.

I imagine most table packages can do these things, I find it hard to find one that is widely adapted and somewhat intuitive to learn.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a package?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm afraid asking for suggestions for packages or software is off topic here. Stack Overflow is really for specific programming problems. But what you are looking for can be achieved in base R. There are also packages that can make data manipulations like you describe a bit easier such as `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it. You can use `melt()` from reshape2. I am not going to post codes here because it is well detailed in the reference below. Good luck.

> https://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape/